# What's the actual runtime in javascript callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to understand JS callback.  In the example below, does A get executed after 100ms or right away?

What's the actual time each A,B,C get executed?
0ms: "A" (or 100ms?)
100ms: "C",
100ms: "B"

```
function wait(ms) {
    let waitUntil = Date.now() + ms
    while (Date.now() < waitUntil) { continue }
}

document.querySelector('#start-button').onclick = () => {
    console.log('A')

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('B')
    }, 50)

    wait(100)

    console.log('C')
}
```

If to modify it to be:

```
function wait(ms) {
    let waitUntil = Date.now() + ms
    while (Date.now() < waitUntil) { continue }
}

document.querySelector('#start-button').onclick = () => {
    console.log('A')

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('B')
    }, 150) // 150ms instead of 50ms

    wait(100)

    console.log('C')
}
```

What's the actual runtime? is it
0ms: A
100ms: C
150ms: B (or 100ms+150ms=250ms)

Comment: Have you tried *running* these code snippets and timing them?

Comment: If you click `[<>]` snippet editor, you can create  [mcve]s and run them and that might even answer your own question

Comment: You can try with [console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/time)

Comment: your `wait` function blocks ALL execution until it is done - so, that 5oms setTimeout can't execute until the wait has finished

Comment: do `console.time('A');console.time('B');console.time('C')` at the top of the click callback - then, where you have `console.log('A')` do `console.timeEnd('A')` ... similarly of `B` and `C` - then you can perform your own timings and see for yourself

Comment: a follow up question, in both cases the "A" actually get executed after quite a wait, but almost the same time as "C". why is that?

Comment: It's *0ms: A 100ms: C 100ms: B* The `setTimeout(fn, 50)` call schedules `fn` to fire at now + 50ms. Since *now* was 0, it's been scheduled to fire at t = 50ms however the engine was busy until t=100ms, so it will execute all the already passed timeouts as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of making this runnable for you. I've also increased the delays dramatically to illustrate the point a bit clearer. You can see that after clicking the start button, you actually don't get any output to the console until the entire lambda onclick function completes its execution, which it can't until the wait call, which blocks the thread, completes. However, the A log statement does execute first and has a timestamp that is the full 2s earlier than the C statement.

Interestingly, the B statement's setTimeout delay is practically ignored and superseded by the wait statement blocking the thread. A small delay of <10ms is introduced in firing that function after the wait block completes. However, if you reduce that wait delay back down to something less than the delay given to the setTimeout, it does execute after the given time delay.

So the times look like this:

```
A: 0, but it's printed after the wait delay
C: the wait delay
B: the wait delay + <10ms
```

It's also worth noting that execution time of a block can factor in an extra ms here or there as you can see by running the blocks. If your delay is 200ms, it could very well show a log time of 201ms. This effect will become more apparent if the block becomes more complex and takes longer to execute.

```js
function wait(ms) {
    let waitUntil = Date.now() + ms
    while (Date.now() < waitUntil) { continue }
}

document.querySelector('#start-button').onclick = () => {
    console.log('A', Date.now())

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('B', Date.now())
    }, 500)

    wait(2000)

    console.log('C', Date.now())
}
```

```html
<button id="start-button">Start</button>
```

And here it is with the shorter wait call.

```
A: 0, but it's printed after the wait delay
C: the wait delay
B: 500ms
```

```js
function wait(ms) {
    let waitUntil = Date.now() + ms
    while (Date.now() < waitUntil) { continue }
}

document.querySelector('#start-button').onclick = () => {
    console.log('A', Date.now())

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('B', Date.now())
    }, 500)

    wait(200)

    console.log('C', Date.now())
}
```

```html
<button id="start-button">Start</button>
```

Comment: "*You can see that after clicking the start button, you actually don't get any output to the console until the entire lambda onclick function completes its execution,*" ***ONLY BECAUSE YOU ARE LOOKING AT THE CONSOLE IN THE SNIPPET!*** Open the browser console and you will see that `A` with a timestamp is printed first *immediately* and the rest of the values after the `wait` finishes. The snippet console should ***NOT*** be taken as gospel. It's a third party implementation and not necessarily representative of how a real console would behave. Works most times but you see there are edge cases.

Comment: "*nterestingly, the B statement's setTimeout delay is practically ignored and superseded by the wait statement blocking the thread*" it's not "ignored"  it's most definitely taken into account. But as always, `setTimeout` will define the *minimum* delay. The thread still has to be free for the task to run. The task will always be put on the callback queue to be picked up by the event loop *when it's free*.

Comment: ^ that also accounts for that delay you observed. The queue is FIFO (a queue, after all) - adding a task to it *doesn't necessarily put it in front*. There might be other tasks that need to be resolved before the timer task is processed. With a busy loop of *seconds*, you can build up a queue of 3-4 tasks, for example and this the timer will add a task at position 4-5. So the front of the queue still takes some time to process.

Answer (score -3):

answer is: you can't know for sure.
what you can "expect" is that A would be printed out immediately as it has no wait time. the rest is undecided.

Javascript engine runs on a single thread. there is nothing that happens "at the same time" but rather "very close together". so the engine may decide that your "busy loop" (wait() function) will get priority while running over the timeout() which was set to 50ms in the first example, and so you will see that C is printed BEFORE B. it could happen, and also different browsers may act differently.

if you had used timeout() on both B and C you might've witnessed more deterministic behavior, but sine you are using a busy loop, all bets are off.

in the second example, 50ms is enough time between B and C that you could expect them to appear in the logical order.

Comment: "*so the engine may decide that your "busy loop" (wait() function) will get priority while running over the timeout()*" no, it cannot "decide" that. That is the *only* valid way to execute the code. If the runtime "decides" to stop the busy wait in order to run a timer,  *then it's not ECMAScript compliant*.

Comment: assuming no other code is running in other frames, the console shouldn't be busy with anything.

Comment: @jabaa - not for me -immediate logging to console occurs in Firefox

Comment: but what's the timestamp on the console output

Comment: @jabaa maybe that's why.. im using brave. i expected "A" to be executed with no delay, but at actually appears almost the same time as "C" after a delay. I guess if im running this in terminal with node, then it shouldn't be like such

Comment: I understand the words you wrote @jabaa was merely reporting the outcome I observed